# Detectar cuando se llega al final del documento utilizando el scroll

Tags: jquery

Este es mi código, y no me genera el mensaje, no sé por qué.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script>

        $(function () {
            $("#contenido").on(function () {
                var iframe = document.getElementById("contenido").contentWindow;
                $(iframe).scroll(function () {
                    if ($(iframe).scrollTop() + $(iframe).height() == $(iframe.document).innerHeight()) {
                        alert("Ultima hoja del Documento");
                        $("#CheckBox1").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                });
            });
        })

    </script>

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <div style="position: relative; width: 100%">
        <div style="width: 800px; background: #000; height: 45px; position: absolute;"></div>
    </div>
    <iframe id="contenido" src="<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/archivos_cartelera/MC-PEI.PDF")%>" type="application/pdf" scrolling="yes" height="800px" width="800px" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="Registrar Visita,..." />

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez esto te funcione:

```
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
        alert("Ha llegado al final de la página");
    }
});
```

Comment: No olvides [edit] tu respuesta y explicar qué hace este código. Tal vez para vos sea obvio su funcionamiento, pero para otros que tengan un problema similar, no.

Comment: Te agradezco Luis, pero igual no aparece el alerta cuando se llega al final del documento.